# Playing a pls file using HTML5 audio

Tags: html, html5-audio

I want to play a .pls file which is an radio file. When I click over this file it plays video in my iIunes (I am using mac). I want to play this pls file in browser especially in Safari as I want to play it in iPhone.

My code:

```
<audio src="radioveronica.pls" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Following is content of my pls file:

```
[playlist]
File1=http://5713.live.streamtheworld.com:80/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title1=Radio Veronica
Length1=-1
File2=http://5713.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title2=Radio Veronica
Length2=-1
File3=http://5713.live.streamtheworld.com:443/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title3=Radio Veronica
Length3=-1
File4=http://5723.live.streamtheworld.com:80/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title4=Radio Veronica
Length4=-1
File5=http://5723.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title5=Radio Veronica
Length5=-1
File6=http://5723.live.streamtheworld.com:443/VERONICAAACCMP3
Title6=Radio Veronica
Length6=-1
NumberOfEntries=6
Version=2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pls file is actually just a text file that contains a link or links to audio streams or other source files.  There is no audio data in the file that can be played directly.

There are only four formats supported by the audio tag (and not in all browsers):

- Ogg Vorbis
- MP3
- WAV
- (Safari actually also supports another format which need not be named)

Comment: so you mean if i pass that link from the pls file it should work??

Comment: @pankaj: Post the contents of the .pls file.

Comment: Only if that link points to an MP3, WAV, or OGG.  The audio tag won't play streaming formats.

Comment: please check content of the pls file

Comment: Those URLs are endpoints for streams.  You'll have to find another source.

Comment: but the pls file containing these urls plays radio in my quicktime player(in mac)

Comment: No, the audio tag does not support streaming.  Hence, you can't use streaming formats.

Comment: if it does not support streaming then how does it plays in my system in iTunes?

Comment: sorry for my last comment I got your point now. can you please suggest me a way to stream radio from a pls file?

Comment: Flash is probably the only solution at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

for shoutcast servers is without stream.nsv(most servers)
for icecast is like you said , for virtual dj is same as shoutcast , example:

```
<html>
    <head><title> Listen To Ma' Radio</title></head>
    <body>
    <audio controls="controls" src="http://50.22.217.113:13679/;&type=mp3"></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

and you can implent another functions , as it it basic html you can even implent in php , enjoy

Comment: This works for VosCast / SHOUTcast. I looked inside my .pls file, pulled out the link and added the mp3 type `http://s9.voscast.com:7376/;&type=mp3` Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can stream thru HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio controls="controls" src="http://IP:port/;stream.nsv&type=mp3"></audio>
```

Fantastic

Comment: Thanks! I opened the `.pls` file in a text editor, found a URL called "File1", and put it as the `src` of an HTML5 `audio` element. I didn't use anything like `;stream.nsv&type=mp3` though.

Comment: I can not stress enough how `/;` is important!!!